# Trouble logging uint8 message fields

Tags: ros-melodic, turtlesim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "turtlesim/Color.h"
#include <iomanip>
void apple(const turtlesim::Color& msg)
{
    ROS_INFO_STREAM(std::setprecision ( 0 )
<< " color=(" << msg.r << " , " << msg.b << " , " << msg.g << " ) ");
    }
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        ros::init(argc, argv, "pose_subscriber");
        ros::NodeHandle n;
        ros::Subscriber pose_sub = n.subscribe("/turtle1/color_sensor", 10, &apple);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

why do my output so strange?
my output is like a lot of this:

```
[ INFO] [1582904454.849200284]:  color=(E , ? , V )
```

can someone tell me where do i did wrong?thanks very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345371/trouble-logging-uint8-message-fields/) by [流水疾翔](https://answers.ros.org/users/51973/%E6%B5%81%E6%B0%B4%E7%96%BE%E7%BF%94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-02-28**:
I provided an answer, but I also re-tagged and edited your question title. The original title was not descriptive enough. In the future, please try to follow the Support guidelines to get the best possible help: http://wiki.ros.org/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is that the three fields you are trying to print are defined as `uint8` in the message. In C++, those are of type `uint8_t`, and the output operator (`<<`) is treating this type like a `char`.

Does the following fix your issue?

```
ROS_INFO_STREAM(std::setprecision ( 0 ) << " color=(" << +msg.r << " , " << +msg.b << " , " << +msg.g << " ) ");
```

Read more here:

- http://wiki.ros.org/msg
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562103/uint8-t-cant-be-printed-with-cout

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2020-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0